# Colored logging messages from Python script within GitLab CI

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I am using a docker container for my GitLab CI and would like to have any output/logging messages in color inside the CI. What I mean: the commands from `.gitlab-ci.yml` are in color, but the outputs of the scripts running `python3 colored_logging.py` are not.

It is so cumbersome to dig through bigger logs without any colors :-(

Here is an example project on GitLab:
https://gitlab.com/ziggyler.ziegler/non-colored-ci/-/jobs/1873125969

Does somebody know how to get colored logging messages in lines 113-117?
Any hints?

Thank you!

Actual output
[image: Actual output]

Desired output
[image: Desired output]

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV TERM xterm-256color

RUN apt-get update && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pip3 install loguru
```

My `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
image: docker:19.03.12

services:
  - docker:19.03.12-dind

stages:
  - build
  - run

build:
    stage: build
    rules:
      - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
        changes:
          - Dockerfile
    before_script:
        - docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
    script:
        - docker build --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest .
        - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
        - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest


run:
    stage: run
    image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
    script:
        - ls -la
        - python3 colored_logging.py
```

My Python code to create the logging messages:

```py
from loguru import logger

logger.debug("This is a debug message!")
logger.info("This is an info logging message!")
logger.warning("This is a waring and should appear in yellow color!")
logger.error("This is an error in red color!")
logger.critical("This is a very critical message!")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the `LOGURU_COLORIZE` variable in your Docker container.

```yaml
run:
    stage: run
    image: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
    variables:
        LOGURU_COLORIZE: "true"
    script:
        - ls -la
        - python3 colored_logging.py
```

Comment: Thank you so much!